# Returning custom string from exception::what()

Tags: c++

How to build a custom string inside what() function of exception class and return it? The following code does not work but presents what I want to achieve:

```
class divide_by_zero : public exception {
public:
   divide_by_zero(int a) : a(a) {}
   const char * what() noexcept {
       stringstream ss;
       ss << "Division " << a << " by zero!";
       return ss.str().c_str();
   }
private:
    int a;
};
```

Comment: Why does not work? Post a complete minimal example. Btw, inherit from std::runtime_exception

Comment: that's a pointer to a temporary object. You'll going to want to create the string in the constructor and store it in a member variable. what() becomes simply "return _message.data();"

Comment: What you do is have the exception create and hold on to the string at construction time that means you need a string member).  Then you can return a pointer to its contents in `what`.

Comment: `return ss.str().c_str();` is a local, and destructed by the time the routine returns.

Comment: Standard Undefined Behavior returning reference to variable which lifetime ends before rerturn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to build a custom string inside what() function of exception class and return it?

Don't do that. It won't work.

Instead, build the custom string inside the constructor, store the string in a member, and return a pointer to the data owned by the member in `what`.

Technically, you can delay building the string until the first call to `what`. The primarily important thing is to store the string in a member rather than a local variable, and to not invalidate the returned pointer. Such delay is unnecessary complexity however, it is simpler to build the string in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your local stringstream is being destroyed too early as it's only local.

Answer (score 0):

Cache the message result with the exception object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::exception;
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;

class divide_by_zero : public exception {
public:
    divide_by_zero(int aa) : a{aa} {}
    const char * what() const noexcept override {
        if (msg.empty()) {
            stringstream ss; 
            ss << "Division " << a << " by zero!";
            msg = ss.str();
        }   

        return msg.c_str();
    }   
private:
    int a;
    mutable string msg;
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw divide_by_zero(75);
    } catch(exception const& ex) {
        cout << "Caught exception " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }   
}
```

UPDATE, or use eerorika's recommendation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::exception;
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;

class divide_by_zero : public exception {
public:
    divide_by_zero(int a) : msg{make_msg(a)} {}
    char const* what() const noexcept override {
        return msg.c_str();
    }
private:
    string msg;

    static string make_msg(int a) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Division " << a << " by zero!";
        return ss.str();
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw divide_by_zero(75);
    } catch(exception const& ex) {
        cout << "Caught exception " << ex.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format and store that string in the constructor and return it later on:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>

class divide_by_zero : public std::exception {
public:
   divide_by_zero(int const a) {
       std::sprintf(buff, formatStr, a);
   }
   const char * what() const noexcept override {
       return buff;
   }
private:
    static constexpr auto& formatStr = "Division %d by zero!";
    char buff[sizeof(formatStr) + 20];
};
```

This does no dynamic allocation, which is better in the case of exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The option that suited my needs best, was to create a static private variable for that class.

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>


class NameException : public exception{
public:
    NameException(std::string name) : name(name) {}

    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        _errorMsg = std::string("Error: name '" + name + "' is not defined");
        return _errorMsg.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string name;

    static std::string errorMsg;
};


std::string NameException::errorMsg;
```

I first attempted to save the compound string in name, but as the function declaration is const meanning variables of the class's object cannot be changed.

It didn't work, but then i remembered that static variables are not a part of a single class's object which means they can be changed inside consts functions.